# Typescript, maintain strongly typed record in return value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a object constructor which takes a `generator` which provides you with a `Record` type to populate.

The returned object will then maintain the keys you provided in the `Record` you construct:

```
interface Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, string | { prop: string }>
{
  //...
}
interface ObjConstructor extends Function
{
  new(generator: (self: Record<PropertyKey, string | { prop: string }>) => void): Obj;
}

let Obj = function(generator: (self: Record<PropertyKey, string | { prop: string }>) => void)
{
  // ...
} as unknown as ObjConstructor

let obj = new Obj((self) => {
    self.a = "text";
    self.b = {
        prop: "text"
    };
    self[self.a] = "text"
});
```

You can then create new keys onto `obj` or alter keys defined in the `generator`:

```
obj[obj.a] = "altered prop"; // Error since typescript does not know that 'a' is defined
obj.a = "altered prop";
obj[obj.a] = "new prop"
obj.c = "new prop";
obj.b.prop = "altered prop"; // Error since typescript does not know that 'b' is 
                             // defined and assigned type { prop: string }
```

As you can see the problem here is that typescript does not know that property `b` has been assigned and so throws an error.

Is there a way I can get the type inference to work here?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)